# Cannot understand null-reference check

Tags: android

I read tutorial from [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html) and cannot understand why author checks `WeakReference` on null-reference? As I know the JM removes only an object reference that `WeakReference` contains but not `WeakReference` object. Should I make this check too?

```
class BitmapDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private String url;
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    public BitmapDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    // Once the image is downloaded, associates it to the imageView
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no point in checking if a final member is null if it's assigned during object construction with a non-null object.  It will always be non-null.  The second check for its imageView reference is completely necessary though.  The original author may have misunderstood about how WeakReference actually works.

Comment: So, if my `Fragment` was removed but it had running `AsyncTask` then all `AsyncTask` fields will available in `onPostExecute()` method all same? Just I bad understand threads with automatic GC.

Comment: Yes, the AsyncTask will continue to run with all of its fields being strongly held until it finally completes.  Then, if nothing else holds a reference to it, it will be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: I understood. Thank you for detail answer!